# Error al obtener el usuario actual en nestjs desde angular

Tags: angular, auth, nestjs

Estoy tratando de obtener el usuario actual en nestjs desde angular y no puedo.
CUando hago las peticiones desde un api tester se obtiene correctamente, pero desde angular no.
aqui el ejemplo:

```
        
@Get('/whoami')
  whoami(@Session() sess:any) {
    console.log(sess)
    return sess.currentUser;    
  }
  
    @Post('/signin')
    async singin(@Body() body: AuthDto, @Session() session: any) {
  
      const user = await this.authService.singin(body);
      session.currentUser= user;
      console.log(session)
        return user;
    }
```

aqui en angular:

```
 whoami() {
    return this.http.get<User>(`${this._baseEndPoint}/whoami`)}

  signin(email: string, password: string) {
    const item = {
      email,
      password,
    };
    return this.http.post<User>(`${this._baseEndPoint}/signin`, item);
  }

 getActualUser() {
    this.whoami().subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('WHOAMI', res); ///salida es null
    });}
```

SI hago las peticiones desde un api tester funciona perfecto

Comment: Hola. Desde el backend, con angular, el console.log te da resultado?. Prueba capturar el error en el subscribe con el segundo parametro (un callback que captura el error)

Comment: Ya resolví hay que incluir credentials:True en la petición para poder interactuar con las cookies entre back y front.Muchas Gracias